# How to EFFICIENTLY upload a a pyspark dataframe as a zipped csv or parquet file(similiar to.gz format)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 130 GB csv.gz file in S3 that was loaded using a parallel unload from redshift to S3. Since it contains multiple files i wanted to reduce the number of files so that its easier to read for my ML model(using sklearn).

I have managed to convert multiple from from S3 to a spark dataframe (called spark_df) using :
`spark_df1=spark.read.csv(path,header=False,schema=schema)`

spark_df1 contains 100s of columns (features) and is my time series inference data for millions of customers IDs. Since it is a time series data, i want to make sure that a the data points of 'customerID' should be present in same output file as I would be reading each partition file as a chunk.
I want to unload this data back into S3.I don't mind smaller partition of data but each partitioned file SHOULD have the entire time series data of a single customer. in other words one customer's data cannot be in 2 files.

current code:
`datasink3=spark_df1.repartition(1).write.format("parquet").save(destination_path)`

However, this takes forever to run and the ouput is a single file and it is not even zipped. I also tried using ".coalesce(1)" instead of ".repartition(1)" but it was slower in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked and the time to run reduced to 1/5 of the original result. Only thing to note is that make sure that the load is split equally amongst the nodes (in my case i had to make sure that each customer id had ~same number of rows)

`spark_df1.repartition("customerID").write.partitionBy("customerID").format("csv").option("compression","gzip").save(destination_path)`

Answer (score 1):

You can partition it using the customerID:

```
spark_df1.partitionBy("customerID") \
         .write.format("parquet") \
         .save(destination_path)
```

You can read more about it here: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-repartition-vs-partitionby/

Comment: this works but the problem here is that the destination path will still have multiple files for each customer

Answer (score 1):

adding to manks [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72237865/3102035), you need to repartition the DataFrame by customerID and then write.partitionBy(customerID) to get one file per customer.
you can see a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238323/how-to-have-a-single-csv-file-after-applying-partitionby-in-pysark/72238408#72238408).

Also, regarding your comment that parquet files are not zipped, the default compression is [snappy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_(compression)) which has some pros &cons compared to gzip compression but it's still much better than uncompressed.